# Aptana Studio 3 + Visual Studio MVC 3 = not working together

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, aptana

I'm working on a web application, where the backend is built in MVC 3. When I run my project in Visual Studio 2010, the app is making jQuery Ajax calls to the IIS to get the data, which is then displayed in the browser/frontend. However, I prefer to use writing HTML/CSS/JavaScript in Aptana Studio 3, and thought that I could call my MVC controller from my project in Aptana.
In Visual Studio, I have to type "Users/ListUsers" as the url for the Ajax call, however, when I try to call the same url by using "http://localhost:51845/Users/ListUsers" in Aptana, the Ajax request is made but there is no data returned, which seem to have something to do with the same origin policy.
Is it possible to make Aptana communicate properly with IIS/ MVC controller or do I have to do all the work in Visual Studio?

What did I do to solve the problem so far?

1) Checked what "http://localhost:51845/Users/ListUsers" returns by using WFetch, which shows the Json Object returned.

2) Fiddled with Aptana > Project > Properties > Preview Settings.

3) Fiddled with Aptana > Run > Run Configurations.

4) Searched Aptana support, stackoverflow and Google.

Thanks for any help or tossing me into the right direction!